# 500 Server Error based on HardDeadlineExceededError

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I have a simple spring web application that only has spring mvc and spring roo setup. For some reason on all of my old app instances, when I uploaded this sample application, it always gets a "hanging/exceeded time" error in the logs. Even in the case of basic spring mvc setup. The logs I've seen are below. I am a bit confused since the same application was working previously until today, and now even the simple deployments to google app engine are returning a 500 error. Any help would be appreciated, but I just want to see if this is an issue people are seeing with spring mvc specifically or with the latest google app engin sdk?:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (c22ac44effde64c8) started at 2012/03/13 15:39:52.285 UTC and was still executing at 2012/03/13 15:40:54.889 UTC.
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-c22ac44effde64c8(Request.java)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:57)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:476)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [warmup requests](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Warmup_Requests).

Comment: Thanks Peter; I'm going to try enabling that now. It was just strange since the same app has been deploying fine for the past few months, but I think I should be "safe" and simply have this enabled as a default. Would you recommend removing the overhead that comes with using extra jars like spring roo or spring security if possible? Or is that simply a matter of personal tradeoffs? (I hope that didn't digress off topic too much)

Comment: I don't know Spring so I couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

This is a localized problem - app engine seems to be having problems system wide, especially badly for M/S applications.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/js5CeRWLQZ0